# SQL Server 2005 Express: back up to a folder on the network

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005-express

I am using this code as a procedure on an application. At the mid-night, it will trigger the procedure.

```
http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View487F82A5-C96B-4660-A070-F7C8B7FC4431.htm
```

I changed this locally back-up:

```
TO  DISK = N''c:\db backup\'
```

to:

```
TO  DISK = N''\\nlbkserver02\backup_devicem01$\'
```

It is working normally on the local machine but it did not work on a network drive. The error details is as following:

```
Cannot open backup device
'\\nlbkserver02\backup_devicem01$\15-Dec-2010
- application 1'. Operating system error 5(error not found). BACKUP
DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

could anyone give me an advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL runs by default under the Localsystem account. that account does not have access to shares on the network as it isn't an authenticated network account.

You should also check the permisions on the share.

Answer (score 0):

[Has the SQL Server server account got write access to this share?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179313.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I added 2 slashes \\ but the quoted code gave only 1. I am sure the path is correct.

Comment: @JoesyXHN: I've fixed your layout

Comment: How can I check whether sql server account got write-access to the share folder?

Comment: @JoesyXHN: same as you would any share and NFTS rights. Have as search: it's not straightforwrd to answer here

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider backing up to the local drive and having another job (outside of SQL) to copy/move the backup to the network drive?

This way, if there is some problem with the network drive (like that computer is offline, the network is down, etc.) the backup will still happen. I would think that just because the network drive is offline you would not want to skip the backup.